# Build mongo shell 3.2.x on ARM (armv7l/arm64/aarch64) - segmentation fault

Tags: linux, mongodb, arm, arm64

Over the past days I tried a lot to get mongo shell running on Ubuntu 16.04 for ARM64 (aarch64) at Linaro cluster. I am currently working on the next release fork for meteorjs on ARM architecture.

TL;DR

While the mongod (DB) is running well after build without seen issues yet, it is not possible to get a running mongo shell [even WITHOUT javascript (mozjs) support] after build.

#### Simplest build:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/mongo-build

cd /tmp/mongo-build

git clone --branch "r3.2.6" --depth 1 https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git

cd mongo

scons --disable-warnings-as-errors --prefix=/tmp/mongo-build/mongo --js-engine=mozjs mongo mongod
```

Even that this build will be run on all tested platforms and architectures (Linux on armv7l, aarch64, amd64) without issues during compiling, the results in case of running programs differs.

#### Running mongo command after build on amd64:

*Just run mongo shell and try to connect to a non existing instance*

```
./mongo mongodb://localhost:5002/sample
```

this will give this output:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
connecting to: mongodb://localhost:5002/sample
2016-07-05T14:10:23.772+0200 W NETWORK  [thread1] Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:5002, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2016-07-05T14:10:23.772+0200 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: couldn't connect to server localhost:5002, connection attempt failed :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:223:14
@(connect):1:6

exception: connect failed
```

#### Running mongo command after build on aarch64/armv7l:

Instead of this, the output on ARMs is just:

```
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.6
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

It seems to me that the TCP connection part might bring up that "SEGMENTATION FAULT" but I can't debug this.

I would be happy about any help to get this run.

Thanks in advance
Tom

Comment: I have added an issue to our github project https://github.com/4commerce-technologies-AG/meteor/issues/57

Comment: I think this question would be more appropriate on AskUbuntu or Superuser. The answer is most likely https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1143022.

Comment: @unixsmurf thanks for feedback - Is there a simple procedure to post question also on other forums without duplicating the content?

Comment: @unixsmurf I dont think that this is mozilla related because I have same behavior also on armv7l (32bit) architecture and more important also WITHOUT JS-ENGINE.

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/85017/how-do-i-move-my-own-question-to-another-stack-exchange-site

Comment: There's no need for the bounty - if you can't get moderator attention, just ask the question again on a site where it would be on-topic and notify us here.

Comment: @unixsmurf I asked on Superuser and they told me StO is the right not SU, the issue is not ubuntu only its based on arm. So what should I do to get a bit more attention?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After running a lot more tries and compiles, I have changed the branch for mongodb release and work with r3.3.9.

While using the same scons parameters it seems to run without any issue. I have not yet digged into details and changes in the versions but to have a running release is fine to me

```
mkdir -p /tmp/mongo-build

cd /tmp/mongo-build

git clone --branch "r3.3.9" --depth 1 https://github.com/mongodb/mongo.git

cd mongo

scons --disable-warnings-as-errors --prefix=/tmp/mongo-build/mongo --js-engine=mozjs mongo mongod
```

Comment: Build system support for aarch64 was only added during the 3.3 development cycle (which is ongoing). In particular, we actually are building the master branch on aarch64 machines in the MongoDB CI system. We do not do so for the 3.2 branch, and it is unlikely that it can be made to work.

Comment: Hi @acm thanks for your reply. I am wondering that r3.2.6 mongod is running fine and without (recognized) issues yet on my aarch64 (linaro cluster). The issue just occurs on the mongo shell and on that it has same issue for armv7 and arm64. Upcoming meteor 1.4 will need (choose) v3.2 branch. Any good idea for decision. Thx, Tom

Comment: MongoDB isn't going to invest in 32-bit builds. The WiredTiger storage engine is 64-bit only, and MMAPv1 can only support 1GB of data in 32-bit addressing. We no longer do any testing of 32 bit builds, and won't fix it if it breaks. So, armv7 will not happen. For ARMv8, there was an important SpiderMonkey fix that went in on master. We are testing ARMv8 on master, but we are not testing it on v3.2 and have no plans to add support there, so the fix is almost certainly not going to be backported. If you want MongoDB on aarch64, you are going to want to wait for MongoDB 3.4.

Comment: @acm Thanks for your information, that will help us to decide next steps. Cheers, Tom

Answer (score 1):

If you issue ./mongo --help the binary still works but the connection has issues dealing with a non existant database. Seg Faulting instead of failing gracefully at the non existant database. Due to a null pointer dereference.

The offending code is in
/src/mongo/client/mongo_uri_connect.cpp

```
    if (!_user.empty()) {
        ret->auth(_makeAuthObjFromOptions(ret->getMaxWireVersion()));
    }
    return ret;
}
```

It is claimed to be effected from 3.2.8 until 3.3.9 here.

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-23126

On another note if you require sharding add "core" to the scons line.
For mongod, mongos and mongo to have them all included with the build.

```
scons --disable-warnings-as-errors --prefix=/tmp/mongo-build/mongo --js-engine=mozjs core
```

A good way around this would be to just point it to an existing database instead of a sample database.

Comment: As commented on github issue, the patch is already in 3.2.8 but still seg fault. only version works until now is 3.3.9. Thanks for your help.